# Displaying text in WindowForms

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I have code to append value from dropdownlist to the textbox. But I am not certain why this does not display text of any kind in the textbox.

```
Try
    ' Add the selected text to the end of the text already in txtExpression textbox
    txtExpression.AppendText(cboOpenParen.SelectedText)
Catch ex As Exception

Finally

End Try
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `.SelectedText` Property...

Use the `.Text` Property....

Code:

```
Try
    ' Add the selected text to the end of the text already in txtExpression textbox
    txtExpression.AppendText(cboOpenParen.Text)
Catch ex As Exception

Finally

End Try
```